# Setting a Global Itemsep Value for Enumerate Environments

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, vertical-spacing, add-vertical-space

Consider the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph\bfseries\arabic*]
\setlength\itemsep{1.5em}
\item Item A %\lipsum[13]
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end {enumerate}

\vspace*{10pt}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph\bfseries\arabic*]
\item Item A
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end {enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

QUESTION: How may I, for example, specify `\itemsep{1.5em}` for all enumerate environments in a document with resorting to inserting this command within each such environment?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally set for `enumerate`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{itemsep=1.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph\bfseries\arabic*]
\item Item A
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end {enumerate}
Text in between.
\begin{enumerate}[label=\emph\bfseries\arabic*]
\item Item A
\item Item B
\item Item C
\end {enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you egreg.